Could not resolve com.mapbox.maps:android:10.17.0
How can i fix this error???
I've been looking for a solution to this error for days. Documentation is very poor. Can someone help
It does not build on Android
* What went wrong:
   > Could not resolve com.mapbox.maps:android:10.17.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :rnmapbox_maps
      > Could not resolve com.mapbox.maps:android:10.17.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/maps/android/10.17.0/android-10.17.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/maps/android/10.17.0/android-10.17.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
   > Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-turf:6.11.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :rnmapbox_maps
      > Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-turf:6.11.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-sdk-turf/6.11.0/mapbox-sdk-turf-6.11.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-sdk-turf/6.11.0/mapbox-sdk-turf-6.11.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
        kotlinVersion = "1.9.22"
        RNMapboxMapsImpl = 'mapbox'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
    }
   allprojects {
    repositories {
        // ...other repos
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = 'mapbox'
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = project.properties['sk-key'] ?: ""
            }
        }
        // ...even more repos?
    }
}
}

 "dependencies": {
    "@rnmapbox/maps": "^10.1.24",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.1"
  },

I followed the installation in the documentation but I'm getting this error. Isn't there a solution to this? It took me hours :/

Your error related with token token or credentials it can not reach to execution time. You need to double check your api token.

My API token has been good for awhile, and this just started happening for me. Not sure what's going on yet.
